# Sort datetime and return index error in Python

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, datetime

I want to sort a list of 'datetime' object and return the index, 
e.g. sort `[(2012, 6, 1, 0, 0),(2010, 1, 1, 0, 0)]` and return `[2,1]`.

I used following python code:

```
>>>date_seq = [datetime.datetime(1993, 3, 25, 0, 0),
   datetime.datetime(1985, 6, 18, 0, 0),
   datetime.datetime(1971, 7, 8, 0, 0)]

>>>sorted(date_seq, key=lambda k:date_seq[k])
```

But got the error message:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not datetime.datetime
```

My questions are

1. Why does the code '***sorted(date_seq)***' work fine, but not '***sorted(date_seq, key=lambda k:date_seq[k])***'?
2. How to get the sorted indices in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mustn't use `key` in this case. It's basically here to sort nested lists, or objects based on one of their attribute, dicts based on their values etc.

```
key=lambda k:date_seq[k]
```

`k` is a `datetime` object because `sorted` iterates over `date_seq` and execute your lambda on each item in it, so he know the sorting order (the output of your lambda must be "comparable", eg, you can use `>`, `<`, `==` and so on on it, which means `__lt__`. `__eq__` are defined, of course the outputs must be comparable between them or an exception will be raised)

For example

```
sorted(date_seq, key=lambda x: x.month)
```

Will sort your dates by ascending month(ignoring of course years and days) :

```
[datetime.datetime(1993, 3, 25, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1985, 6, 18, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1971, 7, 8, 0, 0)]
```

**EDIT for your second question I didn't see :**

`sorted` is not a `map` (or a list comprehension). It cannot change the items in the list, it only sorts them.
You want to use `map` or a list comprehension, and `list.index` function.

```
[sorted(date_seq).index(x) + 1 for x in date_seq]
# outputs [3, 2, 1] for your sample array
```

[Here is documentation for sorted (python 3.6).](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sorted)

Comment: I see why I was wrong. Any idea on returning the index, instead of the sorted list?

Comment: My edit seem to do exactly what you want to do. It takes the sorted list, then get the index in this sorted list of each item in the unsorted list.

Answer (score 0):

You try to sort a list so, you have to use `integer` as list indices. You have use used `k` that is `datetime.datetime` type. So you are getting this error :

```
>>> import datetime
>>> date_seq = [datetime.datetime(1993, 3, 25, 0, 0),
...    datetime.datetime(1985, 6, 18, 0, 0),
...    datetime.datetime(1971, 7, 8, 0, 0)]
>>> sorted(date_seq, key=lambda k:date_seq[0])
[datetime.datetime(1993, 3, 25, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1985, 6, 18, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1971, 7, 8, 0, 0)]
>>> sorted(date_seq, key=lambda k:k.year) # sort according to `year`
[datetime.datetime(1971, 7, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1985, 6, 18, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1993, 3, 25, 0, 0)]
>>> sorted(date_seq, key=lambda k:k.month) # sort according to `month`
[datetime.datetime(1993, 3, 25, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1985, 6, 18, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1971, 7, 8, 0, 0)]
>>> sorted(date_seq, key=lambda k:k.day) # # sort according to `day`
[datetime.datetime(1971, 7, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1985, 6, 18, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1993, 3, 25, 0, 0)]
>>>
```